# Views are not loading with ngRoute

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi I am having an issue with my code here where I can't seem to get my views to load within my template.

Here are my tags:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.6/angular-route.js"></script>
```

Here is my JS:

```
angular.module('dnsApp', ["ngRoute"])

var app = angular.module('dnsApp');

app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider
  .when('/', {
    templateUrl: 'views/reporting.html'
  })
  .when('/reporting', {
    templateUrl: 'views/reporting.html'
  })
  .when('/detectionSummary', {
    templateUrl: 'views/detection-summary.html'
  })
  .when('/operationalMetrics', {
    templateUrl: 'views/operational-metrics.html'
  });
}]);
```

Here is my HTML:

```
 <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="active"><a href="#!reporting"><i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#!detectionSummary"><i class="fa fa-bolt"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="#!operationalMetrics"><i class="fa fa-bar-chart"></i></a></li>
  </ul>
```

Nothing shows up and I am relatively new to AngularJs so any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not declare the module again, change it as

```
//remove this line angular.module('dnsApp', ["ngRoute"])
var app = angular.module('dnsApp', ["ngRoute"])

app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider
  .when('/', {
    templateUrl: 'views/reporting.html'
  })
  .when('/reporting', {
    templateUrl: 'views/reporting.html'
  })
  .when('/detectionSummary', {
    templateUrl: 'views/detection-summary.html'
  })
  .when('/operationalMetrics', {
    templateUrl: 'views/operational-metrics.html'
  });
}]);
```

Comment: angular.js:12759 Failed to load file:///Users/robherman/Desktop/dns_firewall/views/reporting.html: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

Comment: Error: [$compile:tpload] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.6/$compile/tpload?p0=views%2Freporting.html&p1=-1&p2=
    at angular.js:88
    at angular.js:20254
    at angular.js:17051
    at m.$digest (angular.js:18233)
    at m.$apply (angular.js:18531)
    at angular.js:1952
    at Object.invoke (angular.js:5040)
    at c (angular.js:1950)
    at Uc (angular.js:1970)
    at we (angular.js:1855)

Comment: can you create a plunker

Comment: Thank you for that, it does seem to work obviously. I still cannot figure out why I can't get it to load locally tho...

Answer (score 0):

you should add your module js to your tags in your "index".

also a ng-view in your main index.

documentation:https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/directive/ngView